# roots of a polynomial mod $p^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $f = X^2 + uX + v$ be an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ and let $\alpha$ and $-(u+\alpha)$ be it's two distinct roots.

If we consider $f$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})[\alpha]$ it has again only two roots (i.e. $\alpha$ and $-(\overline{u} + \alpha)$ where $\overline{u}$ is reduction of $u$ modulo $p$)

What can we say about the roots modulo $p^n$ ?

Comment: Have you studied $\,p$-adic numbers, Hensel's Lemma and stuff?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $x^2 - p$ with $p$ prime, which is irreducible because it is Eisenstein at $p$. If $x^2 - p = 0 \pmod{p^2}$ for some integer $x$, then $p^2 | x^2-p$, which means $ap^2 = x^2 - p$ and $x^2 - p - ap^2 = 0$. Since $x^2-p - ap^2$ is again Eisenstein at $p$, it is irreducible, hence has no root, which contradicts the fact that $x$ solved the equation in the first place.

So I guess what I'm saying is that in general you cannot assume you will have roots mod $p^2$.

The theorem that works though in this case is called Hensel's lemma ; it allows you to lift roots of a polynomial mod $p$ to roots mod $p^n$ for any integer $n$ in a unique way, assuming some non-degeneracy (i.e. that if $x$ is a root of $f(X)$ mod $p$, then $f'(x) \neq 0 \pmod p$. Note that this is the case for the roots of $x^2 - p$ (which is a double root at $0$ modulo $p$), because if $f(X) = X^2 - p$ then $f'(X) = 2X$ which is zero when evaluated at $0 \pmod p$.

If you want to understand better the situation you should read up on Hensel's lemma. Start by the wiki page and if you need more, elementary number theory books that cover the standard topics will explain how it works in detail.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Hi I guess my problem is that I don't assume that the roots are in $\mathbb{Z}$ so the version of Hensel lemma in wikipedia doesn't seem to apply here right ? Also Hensel lemma tells me that each root that I have (modulo the previous problem) lifts uniquely to a root mod $p^n$ (because there are two distinct roots mod p) but it doesn't tell me that there are no more (I think).

Comment: In fact there are some flaws in my question since it is false that modulo $p$ the polynomial has only two roots. For example $X^2 -2$ has three roots in $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})[\sqrt 2]$

Comment: @Zorba: The roots of $x^2-2$ are not distinct modulo two, so Hensel's Lemma fails.

Comment: AH yes that's true

Comment: @Zorba : Watch it ; the roots of $f(X)$ over $\mathbb Z[X]$ and the roots over $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)[X]$ are not "the same" ; you can't just read the root obtained over $\mathbb Z$ modulo $p$ to obtain the roots in $\mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z$ ; for instance, the polynomial $X^2 - 2$ has roots $\pm \sqrt 2$ in an integral extension of $\mathbb Z$ (namely, $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2]$) but this polynomial has the double root $0$ in $\mathbb Z/2 \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Yes I realized afterwards that my question was wrong.

Comment: Good ; it's okay to make mistakes as long as you see them. :P